# WebServices context problem

Tags: contexts, webservices

I'm using two web services from the same host: [Earth Orientation Center](http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/index.php?index=mission&lang=en)

I can get each one to work on a fresh kernel but I cannot get both of them to work during the same instance of the kernel. I think this is a context problem so I have tried loading each one into their own context.

**The Code** 
Instal the service:

```
Needs["WebServices`"]

InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_MATRICE_EOP.php?wsdl"]
```

Make a call:

```
year = 2005;
month = 12;
day = 31;
hour = 12;
minute = 34;
seconde = 34;
pm = 1;
ut = 1;
nut = 1;
tides = 1;

wservice = 
 MATRICEfromDate[
 LaDate["theyear" -> year, "themonth" -> month, "theday" -> day, 
 "thehour" -> hour, "theminute" -> minute, "thesecond" -> seconde, 
 "thepm" -> pm, "theut" -> ut, "thenut" -> nut, 
  "thetides" -> tides]]
```

This works and I get a matrix.

```
complexType$2200["a11" -> 0.318954, "a12" -> 0.94777, 
 "a13" -> 0.000580507, "a21" -> -0.94777, "a22" -> 0.318954, 
 "a23" -> 0.0000409354, "a31" -> -0.000146358, "a32" -> -0.000563244, 
 "a33" -> 1.]
```

But now if I install the other web service

```
InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_EOP2.php?wsdl"]
```

Then make a call:

```
year = 2005;
month = 12;
day = 31;

wservice = 
 C04fromDate[
  LaDate["theyear" -> year, "themonth" -> month, "theday" -> day]]
```

It also works!

```
complexType$3424["MJD" -> 53735, "x" -> 0.053717, "y" -> 0.384245, 
"UT1UTC" -> -0.661133, "LOD" -> -1.6*10^-6, "dX" -> 0.000228, 
"dY" -> -0.000287, "xerr" -> 0.00014, "yerr" -> 0.000141, 
"UT1UTCerr" -> 1.7*10^-6, "LODerr" -> 0.0000135, "dXerr" -> 0.000098,
 "dYerr" -> 0.000091]
```

So what is my problem? When I go back an run the first function `MATRICEfromDate` I get:

```
SerializeSchemaInstance::children: Invalid children: thehour->12.
```

I cannot get both of them to work consistently in one kernel session. I think is has to do with the context of the `LaDate`

**Edits**

I have tried adding `AllowShortContext -> False` as was suggested. However, this did not work but it help open the door to a better understanding of the problem. I have now explicitly added a context:

```
InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/
server_MATRICE_EOP.php?wsdl", "First`", AllowShortContext -> False]

InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/
server_EOP2.php?wsdl", "Second`", AllowShortContext -> False]
```

I then call the web service with the following functions (I use the same inputs as above)

```
wservice = 
 First`MATRICEfromDate[
  First`LaDate["theyear" -> year, "themonth" -> month, 
  "theday" -> day, "thehour" -> hour, "theminute" -> minute, 
  "thesecond" -> seconde, "thepm" -> pm, "theut" -> ut, 
  "thenut" -> nut, "thetides" -> tides]]
```

and...

```
wservice = 
 Second`C04fromDate[
  Second`LaDate["theyear" -> year, "themonth" -> month, 
   "theday" -> day]]
```

The problem revolves to the context of `LaDate`. Here is a look at the variables in the two contexts:

```
?Second`*

C04fromDate dYerr$2982 MJD$2946   themonth$2872 xerr$2967
complexType$2943 dY$2964 thedate$2939 theyear$2867 x$2949
    dXerr$2979   LODerr$2976 thedate$2939$2987                  
    dX$2961  LOD$2958 theday$2877 UT1UTC$2955 y$2952
```

Notice there is no `LaDate`. Now look at the other context:

```
?First`*

a11$2737 a23$2752 LaDate  thehour$2545 thesecond$2555
a12$2740 a31$2755 MATRICEfromDate theminute$2550 thetides$2575
a13$2743 a32$2758 thedate$2730 themonth$2535 theut$2565
    a21$2746   a33$2761 thedate$2730$2766 thenut$2570
a22$2749 complexType$2734 theday$2540 thepm$2560
```

Here you will find the `LaDate`.

Some how I need to get a `LaDate` into each context because they are different.

Another attempt

I have taken the two  web servers and placed them in separate packages inside the `` Begin["`Private`"]; `` section and then wrote a wrapper function which I exposed via `usage` and still no luck.  I think I'm just going to parse old FORTRAN data files from the [USNO](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/earth-orientation/eo-products)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try adding AllowShortContext -> False to both InstallService functions.

To both:

```
 InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_MATRICE_EOP.php?wsdl", AllowShortContext -> False]
```

and

```
InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_EOP2.php?wsdl", AllowShortContext -> False]
```

Try the following hard coded SOAP Template using URFetch to POST with SOAPAction and content-type header

```
BeginPackage["EarthOrientationMatrix`", {"XML`"}];
EarthOrientationMatrix;
Begin["`Private`"];
EarthOrientationMatrix[EOPYear_, EOPMonth_, EOPDay_, EOPHour_, EOPMinute_, EOPSeconds_, EOPPM_, EOPUT_, EOPNUT_, EOPTides_] := 
Module[{result, payload, response, xmlresponse, vals}, 
payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope \
xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \
xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \
xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
       \t<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   \t\t<ns1:MATRICEfromDate \
xmlns:ns1=\"http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/\">
   \t\t\t<thedate>
   \t\t\t\t<theyear>" <> ToString[EOPYear] <> "</theyear>
   \t\t\t\t<themonth>" <> ToString[EOPMonth] <> "</themonth>
   \t\t\t\t<theday>" <> ToString[EOPDay] <> "</theday>
   \t\t\t\t<thehour>" <> ToString[EOPHour] <> "</thehour>
   \t\t\t\t<theminute>" <> ToString[EOPMinute] <> "</theminute>
   \t\t\t\t<thesecond>" <> ToString[EOPSeconds] <> "</thesecond>
   \t\t\t\t<thepm>" <> ToString[EOPPM] <> "</thepm>
   \t\t\t\t<theut>" <> ToString[EOPUT] <> "</theut>
   \t\t\t\t<thenut>" <> ToString[EOPNUT] <> "</thenut>
   \t\t\t\t<thetides>" <> ToString[EOPTides] <> "</thetides>
   \t\t\t</thedate>
   \t\t</ns1:MATRICEfromDate>
   \t</SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
   response = 
URLFetch[
     "http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_MATRICE_EOP.\
php", "Method" -> "POST", 
 "Headers" -> {"SOAPAction" -> "MATRICEfromDate", 
   "Content-Type" -> "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"}, 
 "BodyData" -> payload];
   xmlresponse = ImportString[response, "XML"];
   result = 
     Cases[Cases[xmlresponse, 
  XMLElement[{"http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/", 
    "MATRICEfromDateResponse"}, {{"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
       "ns1"} -> "http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/"}, _],
   Infinity], 
 XMLElement[_, {{"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", 
      "type"} -> "xsd:decimal"}, {vals_}] -> vals, Infinity];
  Return[result]];
End[];
EndPackage[];


EarthOrientationMatrix[2005, 12, 31, 12, 34, 34, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

{"0.318954397043", "0.947769885372", "0.000580507307", \
"-0.947770051851", "0.318954427996", "0.000040935409", \
"-0.000146358028", "-0.000563243969", "0.999999830668"}

And then the other method

```
BeginPackage["EarthOrientationParameters`", {"XML`"}];
EarthOrientationParameters;
Begin["`Private`"];

EarthOrientationParameters[EOPYear_, EOPMonth_, EOPDay_] := 
  Module[{result, payload, response, xmlresponse, vals}, 
   payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
     <SOAP-ENV:Envelope \
xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \
xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \
xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
 \t<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 \t\t<ns1:C04fromDate \
 xmlns:ns1=\"http://hpiers.obspm.fr/webservice/\">
     \t\t\t<thedate>
 \t\t\t\t<theyear>" <> ToString[EOPYear] <> "</theyear>
 \t\t\t\t<themonth>" <> ToString[EOPMonth] <> "</themonth>
 \t\t\t\t<theday>" <> ToString[EOPDay] <> "</theday>
 \t\t\t</thedate>
 \t\t</ns1:C04fromDate>
 \t</SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
    response = 
    URLFetch[
 "http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_EOP2.php", 
 "Method" -> "POST", 
 "Headers" -> {"SOAPAction" -> "C04fromDate", 
   "Content-Type" -> "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"}, 
 "BodyData" -> payload];
   xmlresponse = ImportString[response, "XML"];
    result = 
Cases[Cases[xmlresponse, 
  XMLElement[{"http://hpiers.obspm.fr/webservice/", 
    "C04fromDateResponse"}, {{"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", 
      "ns1"} -> "http://hpiers.obspm.fr/webservice/"}, _], 
  Infinity], XMLElement[_, _, {vals_}] -> vals, Infinity];
   Return[result]];
End[];
EndPackage[];

    EarthOrientationParameters[2005, 12, 31]
```

Since these methods do not use the WebService context or package you can call them repeatedly. I did not have time to clean up bloat or add in error trapping.

The LaDate Complex type is being overridden by the last Proxy class that is installed in the WebService. This lead me to believe that the order of the WebServices InstallService function may make a difference.

```
BeginPackage["EarthOrientationCenter`", {"WebServices`"}];
 EarthOrientationParameters;
 EarthOrientationMatrix;
 Begin["`Private`"];

 InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_EOP2.php?wsdl"]
 InstallService["http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/webservice/server_MATRICE_EOP.php?wsdl"];

 EarthOrientationParameters[EOPYear_, EOPMonth_, EOPDay_] := 
   Module[{result}, 
    result = 
     C04fromDate[
 LaDate["theyear" -> EOPYear, "themonth" -> EOPMonth, 
  "theday" -> EOPDay,
  "thehour" -> 1, "theminute" -> 1, "thesecond" -> 1, 
  "thepm" -> 1, "theut" -> 1, "thenut" -> 1, "thetides" -> 1]];
   Return[result]];

 EarthOrientationMatrix[EOPYear_, EOPMonth_, EOPDay_, EOPHour_, 
   EOPMinute_, EOPSeconds_, EOPPM_, EOPUT_, EOPNUT_, EOPTides_] := 
   Module[{result}, 
    result = 
     MATRICEfromDate[
      LaDate["theyear" -> EOPYear, "themonth" -> EOPMonth, 
  "theday" -> EOPDay, "thehour" -> EOPHour, 
  "theminute" -> EOPMinute, "thesecond" -> EOPSeconds, 
  "thepm" -> EOPPM, "theut" -> EOPUT, "thenut" -> EOPNUT, 
  "thetides" -> EOPTides]];
    Return[result]];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Executing

```
   EarthOrientationParameters[2005, 12, 13]
 (* EOP`EOPPort`complexType$1935["MJD" -> 53717, "x" -> 0.063063, 
 "y" -> 0.388017, "UT1UTC" -> -0.653458, "LOD" -> 0.0004528, 
 "dX" -> 0.000251, "dY" -> -0.000145, "xerr" -> 0.000117, 
 "yerr" -> 0.00012, "UT1UTCerr" -> 3.*10^-6, "LODerr" -> 0.000014, 
 "dXerr" -> 0.000082, "dYerr" -> 0.000076] *)
```

and

```
    EarthOrientationMatrix[2005, 12, 13, 12, 34, 34, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 (* EOP`EOPPort`complexType$2212["a11" -> 0.0149869, "a12" -> 0.999888, 
 "a13" -> 0.000573122, "a21" -> -0.999888, "a22" -> 0.0149868, 
 "a23" -> 0.0000406349, "a31" -> 0.0000320411, "a32" -> -0.000573667, 
 "a33" -> 1.] *)
```

I repeated the calls multiple times with no errors. This was done without having to deal with SOAP or WSDL files. I also found a solution by modifying the LaDate ComplexType in the C04 method and calling it UneDate instead of LaDate and hosting the WSDL file on a local webserver (anything that can serve a file using HTTP).
 This solution on requires the user set the extra variables to an integer.
ComplexType in the same context are non-commutative? Order matters?

Comment: Thank you but still no luck? If you are also testing make sure that you call each function at least twice because there is an order in which both work. This was also the order I ran the first time giving me false hope

Comment: @c186282 This was the order I ran it as in your first post. The error did not appear. I took a quick look at the WSDL files. Even if the InstallService does not yield a solution. One can always write full SOAP wrapper template to be submitted to the webservice. If the webservice will take HTTP POST parameters then alternative solutions exist.

Comment: Writing WSDL or a full SOAP wrapper falls outside of my skill set (and attention span). I was hoping to use these services as a quick test to other work I'm doing. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Hans: I can confirm this to not work with several versions on windows. As I understand you didn't see the error, which version/OS do you use?

Comment: @AlbertRetey: I originally ran each method once. I did not get the error. As the poster noted after that one should try this repeatedly. I suggested going to SOAP template and HTTP POST. I have posted edits to the original. I am using Windows 7 64 bit M 9.0.0. I am not sure the InstallService context issue is easily solved. I tried context isolation in packages with no success, hence the bloat in XML and URLFetch solution.

Comment: @Hans: o.k., I just wanted to ensure whether or not you also see the same behavior, which I consider a bug and think should be reported as such (which I probably will do). Your hand-crafted HTTP POST calls are of course a very useful workaround and very appreciated, especially because they show that these are simple enough to make the `WebServices` package for such purposes almost dispensable. +1 for that...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I believe I found another workaround by calling the CO4FronDate method with extra defaulted parameters. The resulting SOAP message sent never uses those extra parameters.